# Better translation for "Roadblock" on projects language

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

While creating a plan for a particular project, the first stage would be the analysis of the current state of things, to be able to create an implementation plan for the rest of the project.

The deliverables for that first project phase should be:

- Milestones and **roadblocks**
- Implementation planning

In the Spanish translation "milestones" are clearly *hitos*, "implementation plan" would be *plan de implementación*... but I'm having trouble with **roadblocks**.

The identified **roadblocks** would be a series of issues or aspects that, if not solved nor correctly addressed, would stop the development of the project.

Since they are not exactly risks (*riesgos*), which would be identified in another phase, I haven't been able to come up with a clear and short translation. The Spanish term ***bloqueos*** just doesn't explain the full meaning.

What would be a good, short translation for **roadblock** in this case?

Comment: you are right @aparente001 I should have said "implementation plan", not " ̶p̶l̶a̶n̶n̶i̶n̶g̶"

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying.  I'll just go ahead and delete my obsolete comment.  (I wish there were a self-destruct feature for comments that one could turn on with a timer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo propondría **obstáculos**, dado que un proyecto bien puede ser una *carrera de obstáculos*.

> **[obstáculo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QpTz5mV)**
>
> Del lat. *obstacŭlum*.
>
> 1. m. Impedimento, dificultad, inconveniente.
> 2. m. En algunos deportes, cada una de las dificultades que presenta una pista.

Answer (score 4):

Además de **obstáculo**, propuesto por Carlos Alejo, también hay dos otras posibilidades en que puedo pensar:

> - **[impedimento](http://dle.rae.es/?id=L2WfZNQ)**
>
>   1. m. Obstáculo, embarazo o estorbo para algo.
> - **[traba](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aBTULtF)**
>
>   9. f. Cosa que impide o estorba la fácil ejecución de otra.
>   10. f. *Der.* Embargo de bienes, incluso derechos, o impedimento para disponer de ellos o para algún acto.

Yo optaría por *traba*, personalmente, a pesar de no ser una palabra tan común, por la idea de impedir la *ejecución* de algo, que va bien con la idea de un proyecto que se está llevando a cabo, pero cualquier de las tres expresaría bien el sentido de *roadblock*.

Comment: Me gusta _traba_. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Other alternative could be

[**óbice**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DjqHoal)

> 1. m. Obstáculo, embarazo, estorbo, impedimento.

Comment: óbice.!! Good one. Very rare.

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa podría ser [**contumeria**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AerTB4R)

> 1. f. El Salv. obstáculo (‖ impedimento).

Comment: Interesante, pero circunscrita a una región.